# How to access both directions of ManyToManyField in Django Admin?

Tags: django, django-admin, many-to-many

The Django admin `filter_horizontal` setting gives a nice widget for editing a many-to-many relation. But it's a special setting that wants a list of fields, so it's only available on the (admin for the) model which defines the `ManyToManyField`; how can I get the same widget on the (admin for the) *other* model, reading the relationship backwards?

My models look like this (feel free to ignore the `User`/`UserProfile` complication; it's the real use case though):

```
class Site(models.Model):
    pass
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(to=User,unique=True)
    sites = models.ManyToManyField(Site,blank=True)
```

I can get a nice widget on the admin form for `UserProfile` with

```
filter_horizontal = ('sites',)
```

but can't see how to get the equivalent on the `Site` admin.

I can also get part-way by adding an inline to `SiteAdmin`, defined as:

```
class SiteAccessInline(admin_module.TabularInline):
    model = UserProfile.sites.through
```

It's roundabout and unhandy though; the widget is not at all intuitive for simply managing the many-to-many relationship.

Finally, there's a trick [described here](http://www.eivanov.com/2009/01/manytomany-relations-in-django.html) which involves defining another `ManyToManyField` on `Site` and making sure it points to the same database table (and jumping through some hoops because Django isn't really designed to have different fields on different models describing the same data). I'm hoping someone can show me something cleaner.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here's a (more or less) tidy solution, thanks to http://blog.abiss.gr/mgogoulos/entry/many_to_many_relationships_and and with a fix for a Django bug taken from http://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/5247

```
from django.contrib import admin as admin_module

class SiteForm(ModelForm):
    user_profiles = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(
        label='Users granted access',
        queryset=UserProfile.objects.all(),
        required=False,
        help_text='Admin users (who can access everything) not listed separately',
        widget=admin_module.widgets.FilteredSelectMultiple('user profiles', False))

class SiteAdmin(admin_module.ModelAdmin):
    fields = ('user_profiles',)

    def save_model(self, request, obj, form, change):
        # save without m2m field (can't save them until obj has id)
        super(SiteAdmin, self).save_model(request, obj, form, change) 
        # if that worked, deal with m2m field
        obj.user_profiles.clear()
        for user_profile in form.cleaned_data['user_profiles']:
             obj.user_profiles.add(user_profile)

    def get_form(self, request, obj=None, **kwargs):
        if obj:
            self.form.base_fields['user_profiles'].initial = [ o.pk for o in obj.userprofile_set.all() ]
        else:
            self.form.base_fields['user_profiles'].initial = []
        return super(SiteAdmin, self).get_form(request, obj, **kwargs)
```

This uses the same widget as the `filter_horizontal` setting, but hard-coded into the form.

Comment: Anybody know of an updated version of this idea that's updated for django 1.4? For one, the bug has (in the last two years) been fixed, and for that matter I'm not sure why the SiteAdmin scope should have any idea what user_profiles means. And in fact, I'm currently getting the error

Exception Type: ImproperlyConfigured
Exception Value: 
'HospitalAdmin.fields' refers to field 'user_profiles' that is missing from the form.

Of course, the model names are different, but the structure is the same. Hospital=Site.